# How to display NSPopover next to a button of another window?

Tags: macos, cocoa, nspopover

I have seen this feature in an application named [Moom](http://manytricks.com/moom/).

This looks like this:
 [image: Moom capture]

Is there a clean way to decorate windows in a such way, or should I just create some kind of application which happens to be just on top of the maximize button, transparent or with a 0x0 frame, and create an NSPopover in this application ?

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for the pointer to this app – looks really handy.

As for how it's done.  Notice that it uses the accessibility API – it needs access when you install it.  The app loos like it sets itself up as an Accessibility client and then receives notifications when certain UI elements are focused (hence the zoom button hover).  See here: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Accessibility/Conceptual/AccessibilityMacOSX/AboutOSXAccessibility/AboutOSXAccessibility.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001078-CH254-DontLinkElementID_18

From there it's not hard to create an overlay window that aligns with that the target UI element (ie. the Zoom button).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to greg's anwer. I did some investigation and found this:

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AppKit/Reference/NSAccessibility_Protocol_Reference/index.html#//apple_ref/c/data/NSAccessibilityFocusedUIElementChangedNotification

Register your app as accessibility client and listen for `NSAccessibilityFocusedUIElementChangedNotification`. If the focused UI element is the zoom button of a window, then create a popover on proper position.

I am going to try this. I will post more whenever I can.

Comment: Hey Tyler! Were you able to mimic the Moom's behaviour?

Comment: Nope. It is extremely hard. I have no idea how Moom did it.